# Is there url_for() in eve?

Tags: python, flask, eve

We know in Flask, there is `url_for()` for endpoint,
like `url_for('edit', _external=True)`
I what to ask what's the best practice in python eve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since eve is Flask application `url_for` works well.
e.g.

```
$ python manage.py shell
In [1]: from flask import url_for

In [2]: url_for('home')
Out[2]: '/'

In [3]: url_for('users|resource')
Out[3]: '/users'
```

In the above example `users` is one of the collection. There are few more that would work conditionally like `'users|item_lookup`, `users|item_post_override` etc. (They don't work on my setup due to my own settings.py file)

To learn more, have a look at the [flaskapp.py](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/flaskapp.py) file, and search for `add_url_rule`